# xml parsing error handling or how to put XMLTextReader's cursor back to start?

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing, xmltextreader

I've got a function `api_request` which takes API method as an argument, and returns `XMLTextReader`

```
Shared Function api_request(method As String) As XmlTextReader
request_text = method & ".xml"
 url = "https://api.vk.com/method/" & request_text & "&access_token=" & token
 Return New XmlTextReader(url)
End Function
```

I call this function from different places to make request to site API and depending on the method results are parsed very differently.

So in each method I have something like this:

```
Dim s As Xml.XmlReader = api_request("users.get")
While s.Read
        If s.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then
          If s.Name = "user" Then
              curr_user=s.ReadElementContentAsString            
          ElseIf s.Name = "error" Then
             error_handler(s, "user.get")
          End If
       End If
End While
```

As you may see, I have the code `ElseIf s.Name = "error" Then error_handler(s, "user.get")`. This is because when error happens, server always returns something like this:

```
<error>
<error_code>4</error_code>
<error_msg>Incorrect signature</error_msg>
</error>
```

This is parsed in `error_handler` Sub, and depending on the error following actions are chosen.

This code works, but I have to check if I encounter error like that  `ElseIf s.Name = "error"` **every** time, though all the methods call the `api_request` function. Is it possible to check for error in api_request function before returning the Reader? The problem is if I start reading xml there, and there isn't an error, I can't anyhow position the Reader to the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't change your position with an `XmlTextReader`, the only other solution would be to load the entire XML document into memory.  Presumably the `XmlTextReader` is going to download the entire XML file into memory when it first reads it anyway, so any performance hit should be negligible.  I would suggest something like this:

```
Shared Function api_request(ByVal method As String) As XmlDocument
    request_text = method & ".xml"
    url = "https://api.vk.com/method/" & request_text & "&access_token=" & token
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(New XmlTextReader(url))
    Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("error")
    If node IsNot Nothing Then
        Try
            Dim errorCode As Integer = Integer.Parse(node.SelectSingleNode("error_code").InnerText)
            Dim errorMessage As String = node.SelectSingleNode("error_msg").InnerText
            errorHandler(errorCode, errorMessage, method)
            doc = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception("Improperly formatted error response: " + doc.InnerXml, ex)
        End Try
    End If
    Return doc
End Function
```

And then in the method that calls `api_request`, do something like this:

```
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = api_request("users.get")
    If doc IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("path_to_user/user")
            curr_user = node.InnerText
        Next
    End If
```